# Pandas how to replace NaN in rows with duplicate keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
  id  item  item_cost order_total
  1   A         6          10
  1   B         4          NaN
  2   A         5          5
  3   C         12         12
```

There are duplicate keys (column 'id') which relate to a specific order. order_total is a sum of each item_cost with the same id. I would now like to duplicate the order_total into each row of the same order. E.g. both rows with id = 1 should have an order_total of 10. One of them has NaN.

This dataframe is simply read in from a csv so I have done no calculations on any of these columns.

The simplified logic I am trying to achieve is: if column id is a duplicate, fill NaN values with the non-NaN value from a row with the same id.

I have tried the following code:

```
print(df.groupby('id',as_index=False).sum())
```

However, the issue here is that I lose the item name which I need to use to perform further analysis.

Comment: print(df.groupby('id') ["order_total"].sum()

Comment: @FaikaMajid - thanks, however this doesn't allow me to see what items are part of the order any longer. It prints out the total value of each order with same id, however I can not see which items were part of that order. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: if dataframe is small you can use iterrows to do this. In that first use ths original dataframe and do a query on this dataframe where order_total is nan,. Then iterate over both and check if id is same put value of order in 2nd dataframes order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['order_total'] = df.groupby('id').order_total.transform('first')

print(df)

   id item  item_cost  order_total
0   1    A          6         10.0
1   1    B          4         10.0
2   2    A          5          5.0
3   3    C         12         12.0
```

Comment: perfect, thank you, this has worked exactly as expected! I have never seen the .transform function so will read up on it to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Glad it worked! I maybe edited the answer while you were trying it out. I made some unnecessary operations before the edit.